# Multiple photogrammetry models in one scene

Tags: animation, physics, photogrammetry

hopefully this hasn't been asked before; I had this idea to have a scene in a Unity game project that I'm making where I would have multiple photogrammetry scanned models of objects, and animate them to be floating around in the air. I've been trying to do the animation in Blender, but with multiple models in one project scene everything has gone incredibly slow and I fear it/my computer doesn't have the power to process all those scanned models at once and be able to make movement out of them. Does anyone know if this seems a possible idea or I need to use something smaller than scanned 3D models?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, photogrammetry objects are pretty detailed with a high amount of polygons and high-res textures. That is pretty heavy on the CPU, GPU, and RAM of your machine. So unless you have access to a very high-powered computer, you will have to simplify your models first.

For example, you could load each single object into blender first and use the "decimate" modifier on it. Play around with the settings, until you get the lowest possible polygon count while maintaining a sufficiently nice look. Then, "apply" the modifier and save/export the object. Afterwards, your machine should be able to handle several of these objects at the same time.
Also, you can possibly load the textures into a raster image processor of your choice (eg. GIMP) and scale it down to something like 50% and save it. This will reduce memory usage further and may go completely unnoticed, unless you really need the high detail, eg. for close-up shots.

If you want to go very low on the polygon count while maintaining a high-quality look, you should look into the "baking" of "normal maps". This is a somewhat advanced technique, so I will not go into too much detail, but I encourage you to search for tutorials with these keywords.